# Cannot convert value of type '[UserModel]' to expected argument type '[AnyHashable : Any]?'

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

[image]

i am getting this error when trying to pass model in userInfo params

Comment: Post code and errors as text and not as images.

Comment: it is just a notification  center not 100 liines of codes. so i share screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a dictionary, you need a key. You can then pull it out on the receiver by key, or pull the first item from the dictionary.

```
userInfo: ["model":self.userModel]
```

Comment: then how can i retrive them when observer is called

Comment: @keshav `userInfo["model"]`